# Origen de las cosquillas

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

Al ver un video de *¿Es posible morirse de risa?* (perdón la publicidad), mencionaban el término cosquillas, del día a día y hasta donde averigüé, universal a nivel hispanohablante. Me picó la curiosidad de la etimología y el origen del término y, oh sorpresa, aparece como *voz expresiva* en el DLE. Consultando otro poco, sugieren que surge de la [onomatopeya ksksks](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cosquillas). La verdad, sin haber encontrado otras explicaciones, no me convence de mucho. Intente comparar con lenguas romances pero el término latino *titillationem* (mencionado en el diccionario en 1780) no ayuda mucho y si nos vamos desde el rumano hasta el gallego... encontramos varias palabras que no tiene relación con nuestras cosquillas, así que tocaría buscar otro rumbo de inicio.

¿Existe otro posible origen de la palabra? ¿Hace cuanto surgió el cambio de las *titilaciones* latinas a las *cosquillas* españolas?

Answer (score 2):

**Corominas** indica que está formada a partir de un radical K-S-K de creación expresiva.  y, en otras lenguas, desde radicales similares, también de creación expresiva.

Answer (score 1):

Según [José Cánovas](http://josecanovas.com/diccionarioetimologico/c.html) el origen es euskérico (es decir, vasco). [Kosk](https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/es/traducir/euskera-espa%C3%B1ol/kosk) es "mordida suave, toque, melladura" e Illa es "menudo, delicado".

> Kosk + Illa => Koskilla => Cosquilla